# Gitlab: Use Dependency Proxy from outside a group?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to use Gitlab's Dependency Proxy for a private project not in a group?

It seems wasteful to create a single group per project (as they may not be related) just to cache container images. Besides, what if the project needs to use images from multiple groups (without being associated with multiple groups)?

I am using a docker runner, and the docs describe a `DOCKER AUTH_CONFIG` variable, but:

- Setting it in `gitlab-ci.yaml` would expose secrets in the repo
- Setting it elsewhere means hard coding a username/password, which I'd rather avoid and use pre-existing variables such as `CI_REGISTRY_USER` and `CI_JOB_TOKEN`

I also thought about creating a Deploy Token in the group, but the docs also say those are only for projects within the group.